# "Hasn't been as bad as they had feared" or "hasn't been as bad as they feared"

Tags: grammar, present-tense, perfect-aspect

I can't find other questions and/or information about the forms / tense I'm using in this sentence as most questions seem to be about the difference between "hasn't" or "hadn't".

Is the correct phrasing

- The storm has not been as devastating as many had feared, or
- The storm has not been as devastating as many feared

And, if either are semantically correct, what is the difference between these sentences?

Comment: Both correct; the second economises, not bothering to _underline_ the fact that the apprehension dated from before the storm actually hit.

Comment: Most people today would probably just say *It wasn't as bad as we feared*. There's nothing *wrong* with Past Perfect *...as we **had** feared*, but that would usually be reduced to *...as **we'd** feared*, with the **/d/** so "de-emphasised" it would often be almost impossible to hear anyway. For the initial clause, Simple Past *The storm **wasn't** as devastating...* is more likely unless the speaker is very focused on the (unexpectedly minor) effects - for example, a reporter pointing to the surrounding (non-devastated) environment as she speaks.